# ¿Hay forma de convertir archivos vbhtml a html?

Tags: html, vb, cpanel

estoy migrando la web de un cliente, cuyos archivos son con la extensión .vbhtml . Al parecer es Visual Basic, pero mi servidor de cPanel no los puede interpretar y no encuentro mucha info sobre el tema. Existe alguna forma de recuperar esos archivos para convertirlos a otros que sí sean legibles para el hosting?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre y cuando los `vbhtml` no tengan código de visual basic y solo contengan html puedes copiarlas a un html y funcionarán sin problema.

Si tienen código visual basic entonces necesitarás un servidor que soporte visual basic..